# C# NO Mapping exists from object type systems.windows.forms.textbox

Tags: c#, sql, object, types, mapping

I know its a in here somewhere but I cannot find the error:

```
txtDealID.Text = Properties.Settings.Default.CurDealNo.ToString();
string server = Properties.Settings.Default.SQLServer;
string constring = "Data Source=" + server + ";Initial Catalog=Propsys;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=sa;Password=0925greg";
SqlConnection conDataBase = new SqlConnection(constring);
SqlCommand cmdDataBase = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM Agents WHERE DealID=@DealID", conDataBase);
cmdDataBase.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DealID", txtDealID);
SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter();
sda.SelectCommand = cmdDataBase;
DataTable dbdataset = new DataTable();
sda.Fill(dbdataset);
BindingSource bSource = new BindingSource();
bSource.DataSource = dbdataset;
dataGridView1.DataSource = bSource;
sda.Update(dbdataset);
```

Comment: Looks like you come from a VB background. txtDealId does not have any kind of "defaut" properties and you need to specify explicitly - that is -    txtDealId.Text in this case.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is here:

```
cmdDataBase.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DealID", txtDealID)
```

In fact, here you're passing to SqlCommand not the text entered into your textbox, but textbox itself.

It should be

```
cmdDataBase.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DealID", txtDealID.Text)
```

Also, avoid using `AddWithValue` and use `Add` method override with explicit type of parameter.

See [Can we stop using AddWithValue already](http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/) article describing possible problems can occur while using `AddWithValue`.

Comment: Sorted....Many thanks. It drives me crazy when you spend hours searching for the error and its right in front of you....